# Intuitive interpretation for some variations of random variable times its pdf

Tags: statistics

I need help to interpret the following expression.

D,w = random variable

f(D) = probability distribution function

---

$A = \int_0^\infty f(D) D dD$
then, A is the mean for all D values that we have, this is the definition of expected value.

$B = \int_w^\infty f(D) (D-w) dD$
Does it mean that B is the mean for all D values which are larger than w?

$G = \int_w^\infty f(D) \frac{(D-w)}{w}dD$
This one, I really don't get it. What does it mean?

Can someone give me the intuitive understanding for those 2 expression (B and G)?

---

This picture is from the paper that I am trying to understand.
[image]

Comment: Presumably $\dfrac{D-w}{w}$ is supposed to be the probability that a large grain spans the linewidth

Comment: It's hard to help without more context. Your $A$ is indeed $E[D]$, but B and G do not seem to have some direct interpretation (without context).